# Переход на страницу, используя DOM - дерево

Tags: javascript, dom, браузер

```html
<div class = "turbolink_scroller has-cart" id="container">
  <article>
    <div class="inner-article">
      <h1>
        <a class="name-link" href="/shop/bags/v08oxnl69/vwl3p5cav">Backpack</a>
      </h1>
      <p>
        <a class="name-link" href="/shop/bags/v08oxnl69/vwl3p5cav">Red</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Всем доброго времени суток.
Это фрагмент кода кое-какой страницы. Мне нужно через браузерную консоль открыть эту ссылку (`<a>` в `<p>` и `<a>` в `<h1>` являются одними и теми же ссылками.) То есть на сайте есть две кнопки (Backpack и Red), мне нужно сымитировать в консоли клик пользователя по любой из этих кнопок.
Уже облазил много ресурсов, но так и не смог добиться нужного результата.
Если кто-то знает, как решить эту проблему, поделитесь, пожалуйста, со мной своими идеями.
Спасибо за проявленное внимание.

Comment: `document.querySelecor(".name-link").click()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто то [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

```
document.querySelecor(".name-link").click()
```

Если совсем универсально, то

```
function callEvent (element, event) {
    if(document.createEventObject) {
        element.fireEvent("on" + event);
    } else {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, false, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
callEvent(document.querySelecor(".name-link"), "click"); // или любое другое событие
```